# How to modify Microphone data in python?

Tags: python, pyaudio, microphone

I try to build a system that can be used to modify sound from the microphone when I talk. For example, when I use google meet or Zoom and I run the program I can apply any filter like scale-pitch to my microphone in real-time.
I try this code to open my microphone:

```py
import pyaudio
import wave

chunk = 1024  # Record in chunks of 1024 samples
sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16  # 16 bits per sample
channels = 2
fs = 44100  # Record at 44100 samples per second
seconds = 3
filename = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  # Create an interface to PortAudio

print('Recording')

stream = p.open(format=sample_format,
                channels=channels,
                rate=fs,
                frames_per_buffer=chunk,
                input=True)

frames = []  # Initialize array to store frames

# Store data in chunks for 3 seconds
for i in range(0, int(fs / chunk * seconds)):
    data = stream.read(chunk)
    frames.append(data)

# Stop and close the stream
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
# Terminate the PortAudio interface
p.terminate()
```

But I can apply filter to the sound data only when I read it, but I can not apply the filter as a defualt setting of the microphone.

Comment: This is one of those places where it's really a tool selection question (and platform-specific; different tools for Windows vs Linux vs MacOS), not a Python question as such. And tool selection questions are off-topic here.

Comment: One class of option involves loopback-routing. Another involves network-remoted audio devices -- or of course one can hack up a physical loopback by connecting a line-out one program plays to to a second one a different program uses as input. I'm sure there are more approaches I'm not thinking of right now.